# How do I make sure that a java program is compatible with Java Enviornment 6?

Tags: java

How do I make sure that my java program is compatible with Java Enviornment 6?

Comment: By trying to compile it with a jdk 1.6 compiler?

Comment: and then running it with jre 1.6 ...

Comment: http://notroswell.com/technical-articles/java-version-mismatch/ just check this one

Comment: Variants of this question have been asked twice today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run all your tests with the target JVM.

If they pass, your application is by definition compatible with that JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Try Java Compatibility Test Tools. See details from [here](http://jcp.org/en/resources/tdk).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `-target 1.6` to the compiler. However, this does NOT guarantee that the bytecode runs with 1.6. It may fail at runtime with Linkage Error when your code uses later API that is not available in 1.6.

You can use [Animal Sniffer](http://mojo.codehaus.org/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/) to detect you code's compatibility with certain Java version.

Or just use a 1.6 compiler ... this is probably the best approach. Always use the lowest compiler version you need to be compatible with.